# Magento 2 : Cron not working as per scheduled time

Tags: cron, magento2

I have scheduled my cron in the **crontab** but it's not getting scheduled. I have checked in the table **cron_schedule** but no entry found. I'm setting it according to the server time in UTC format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="reminder_emails" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\ReminderEmails" method="execute">
            <schedule>10 9 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

The cron get executed corrected to the expression like `* * * * *` and `*/5 * * * *` but not any specific time. Please help me get the format correct.

Answer (score 1):

What enviroment you use to dev (window, mac or linux). Please make sure you had config cron for magento 2. You can use command 'crontab -e' in linux to make sure cron havd config for magento.https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the right format is :

```
<schedule>10 */9 * * *</schedule>
```

It means it will run every 9 hours at minute 10.

Example 00:10 , 9:10 ....

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [link](https://crontab.guru/) to check your cron job timing format

Also, you can use command **crontab -l** to check cron configure on magento.

You can schedule your cron job using this command: **php bin/magento cron:run --group="default"**